# Laravel change project name issue

Tags: laravel

can someone tell me how to solve this issue

```
Cache store [] is not defined.
```

I am trying to change projects name. I am always doing same way:

1. Change APP_NAME in config/app.php
2. change APP_NAME in .env
3. run **php artisan config:cache** and **php artisan config:clear**

But these two commands are showing me error and I could not find solution on internet.

Both lines of code drop same error here is image of full report:
https://prnt.sc/u1w9cb

Here is config/app.php

```
return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Application Name
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This value is the name of your application. This value is used when the
    | framework needs to place the application's name in a notification or
    | any other location as required by the application or its packages.
    |
    */

    'name' => env('APP_NAME', 'CHATTY'),
```

Comment: don't change the `config/app.php` and then check

Comment: @Berto99 same issue still

Comment: try `php artisan cache:clear` (also post the config file please)

Comment: What is your cache driver ? `CACHE_DRIVER` in your **.env** file and loaded with this line `'default' => env('CACHE_DRIVER', 'file'),` in **config/cache.php**

Comment: @ClémentBaconnier problem solved .. just made another project hahaha and this time I done the same as I did in this one where issue appeared and this time it worked just fine. I've probably deleted something by accident.

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell how you're trying to grab your config value without seeing your actual code, but ensure you're using the `config()` helper. For example, `$app_name = config('app.name');`

Also make sure that in your `config/app.php` that your app name value looks like this: `'name' => env('APP_NAME', 'YourAppNameHere')`

Comment: only where I am using config() is like this 


 <a class="navbar-brand" href="{{ url('/') }}">
                    {{ config('app.name', 'Laravel') }}
                </a>